# RDLC is empty in google chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc

I am using RDLC report in my application, its working fine in firefox and shows report correctly, but in googlechrome it shows empty page with only the report header. I searched a lot with no answer.
Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

I would use the plug in 'IE-Tab' for Google Chrome as I develop for SSRS in 2008R2 and 2012 all the time.  Chrome as far as I know has issues with showing SSRS reports in RDL and RDLC types as far I have seen.  I use 'IE tab' and it works fine and I have not been 'forced' to use IE for some time.